# Identify the text type in NASM

Tags: nasm

My purpose is to create a program in NASM, where one of its functions needs to know what type of data is being used, (string, decimal, hexadecimal, etc). But I don't know very well how to do it without it taking up a lot of lines of code. Someone could help me, please. Thank you.

Comment: Write it in a higher-level language first. Once you have an algorithm that works, translate it into assembly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a byte to define the byte of variable, eg.: 1-string 2-dec 3-hex and another byte to know the size of it
so we have 01 05 GREEN... 5 sized string "green" or still 02 01 32 as a byte decimal 32 or 50...

Answer (score 0):

1. Don’t trust user input.
   Your algorithm must positively confirm supplied data is indeed a numeric string.
2. Once you’ve determined the type, you can select and `call` one of three (sub‑)functions `foo_decimal`, `foo_hexadecimal`, `foo_string`.
   This is how compilers for *high-level* languages (can) implement (static) function overloading.
3. A [`struc`](https://nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc5.html#section-5.9) with a data type prefix [like Mario August suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70999624) is definitely nice to have if you are processing the same data multiple times.
   Your functions will still need to have *some* kind of branching though.